# How to append to an immutable List?

Tags: scala

When I run below code the size of userList is 0. I expect it to contain objects of type User as I am appending to them below. I'm not appending to the List userList correctly ?

```
object SimilarityData {

  val userList = List.empty[User]
  case class User(id: String, nCoordinate : Int) 

  def getUsers(): List[User] =
    {

      userList :+
        new User("1", 101010101) :+
        new User("2", 111011101) :+
        new User("3", 101010101) :+
        new User("4", 101110101) :+
        new User("5", 101110101) :+
        new User("6", 101011101) :+
        new User("7", 101010101) :+
        new User("8", 101010101) :+
        new User("9", 111000111);

      userList
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(userList.size)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending to an immutable `List` appends the element to a new `List`. Since `userList` is immutable it is and will always be `List.empty` which is what it was assigned.

To get the size of `userList` after appending users return the new `List` that was created with the appends to get the right size. In Scala the last line in a method is the return value. Since `userList :+ ...` returns a new `List` this is equivalent to assigning `userList` to some return value and returning that.

```
object SimilarityData {

  val userList = List.empty[User]
  case class User(id: String, nCoordinate : Int) 

  def getUsers(): List[User] =
    {
      userList :+
        new User("1", 101010101) :+
        new User("2", 111011101) :+
        new User("3", 101010101) :+
        new User("4", 101110101) :+
        new User("5", 101110101) :+
        new User("6", 101011101) :+
        new User("7", 101010101) :+
        new User("8", 101010101) :+
        new User("9", 111000111);    
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(getUsers.size)
  }

}
```

Run it:

```
scala> SimilarityData.main(Array[String]())
9
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `List` is prepend-oriented data-structure. Appending to it has *O(n)* complexity, while prepending - *O(1)*
2. `List` is an immutable data-structure, that's why you can't modify an existing value, but you can get a new value based on it. Think of `String` or `Int`.

Taking the above into account, to achieve optimal results you should update your code to the following:

```
  def getUsers : List[User] =
    new User("1", 101010101) +:
    new User("2", 111011101) +:
    new User("3", 101010101) +:
    new User("4", 101110101) +:
    new User("5", 101110101) +:
    new User("6", 101011101) +:
    new User("7", 101010101) +:
    new User("8", 101010101) +:
    new User("9", 111000111) +:
    userList
```